# PyFirmata Button Doesnt Change Values

Tags: python, arduino, servo, pyfirmata

Im Using Pyfirmata For A While, And I Want To Connect A Joystick Button On It, I Made The Code (AI) And It Didnt Work, It Keeps Changing Like "True, False, False, True, True..." and doesnt do nothing, heres my python code (PS: im using standart_firmata)

```
from pyfirmata import *
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
import random
from math import *

class IA:

    def __init__(self, board, maquina, analogx, analogy) -> None:
        self.board = board
        self.maquina = maquina
        self.analogx = analogx
        self.analogy = analogy
        self.button = self.board.get_pin("d:8:i")



        self.previous_button_state = 0

        self.sr = sr.Recognizer()


    def record(self):
        with self.sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("gravando")
            self.sr.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

            audio = self.sr.listen(source)
            
            try:
                frase = sr.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')
                frase = frase.lower()
                pass

            except sr.UnkownValueError:
                self.maquina.say("Não Entendi")
                self.maquina.runAndWait()
                self.main()

            if (frase == "olá"):
                sentences = ["Olá","Opa","Eae","Oi","Haha Eae"]
                sentence = random.choice(tuple(sentences))
                
                self.maquina.say(sentence)
                self.maquina.runAndWait()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            print(floor(self.button.read()))
            time.sleep(1)

    def greet(self):
        self.board.digital[2].write(135)
        self.maquina.say("Olá! Sou Jesse, Bem Vindo Ao Meu Sistema")
        self.maquina.runAndWait()

        self.board.digital[2].write(90)
        self.maquina.say("Posso Fazer Varias Coisas")
        self.maquina.runAndWait()

        self.board.digital[2].write(135)
        self.maquina.say("Apenas Aperte No Botão Do Joystick E Fale Oque Quer! Divirta-se")
        self.maquina.runAndWait()

        self.board.digital[2].write(90)
        self.board.digital[3].write(75)
        self.main()
```

If anyone can help me, i will be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [c++]?

Comment: @DrewDormann its because arduino code is coded with c++